# MariaDB: ALTER TABLE syntax to add a FOREIGN KEY?

Tags: mariadb

what'S wrong with the following statement?

```
ALTER TABLE submittedForecast
  ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (data) REFERENCES blobs (id);
```

The error message I am getting is

```
Can't create table `fcdemo`.`#sql-664_b` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

Comment: Note that the datatypes, order of table definitions, etc, can cause err 150.

Answer (score 11):

This works for me on MariaDB 10.1.8:

```
CREATE TABLE `submittedforecast` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `data` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `data` (`data`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;    
CREATE TABLE `blobs` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `content` BLOB NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE submittedForecast
  ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (data) REFERENCES blobs (id);
```

Can you give your MariaDB version number and a complete example including the `CREATE TABLE` statements for `submittedForecast` and `blobs`?

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know the syntax for adding two foreign keys in the one statement? Or does it require two statements to run?

Not critically important of course, can always just run two statements, but it would be nice to know.

Comment: Never mind, just figured it out. You have to repeat **all** the keywords, "ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY" after each separating comma. Not verbose at all >:-)

Answer (score 5):

No idea if you already solved this but make sure both engines and collations match between tables (e.g: latin1 to latin1 and InnoDB to InnoDB).

I was having the same issue and by switching these I managed to get it working.

Comment: Additional info: MyISAM tables do not support foreign keys. As @david-arguedas said, the tables must be InnoDB to InnoDB.

Comment: Also make sure the data types match, for example, if the primary key in the table being referenced is **unsigned integer,** be sure the foreign key is also **unsigned integer.** We ran into numerous occasions where somebody didn't follow convention and used *signed integer* in either the referenced or the referencing table, which caused heartburn trying to add the key definitions.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and is actually pretty easy to solve, you have name the constraint, something like this should do:

```
ALTER TABLE submittedForecast ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_submittedForecast` 
  FOREIGN KEY (data) REFERENCES blobs (id)
```

If you would like more cohesion also add at the end of the query

```
 ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT
```

This could also be a different fields error so check if the table key and the foreign key are of the same type and have the same atributes.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, too. When checking the definition of the fields, I noticed that one field was defined as INT and the other as BIGINT. After changing the BIGINT type to INT, I was able to create my foreign key.

Comment: Depending on whether the BIGINT was intentional or not, it might have been a better choice to change the INT to BIGINT instead. The existing BIGINT type could mean the values were expected to go beyond 2147483647 signed (or 4294967295 unsigned). If storage space is not an issue, it's safer to move from a smaller to a bigger datatype, and not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same issue and after looking at my table structure, found out that my child table's foreign key clause was not referencing the primary key of parent table. Once i changed it to reference to primary key of parent table, the error was gone.